Edited: longitudinal view of different modes of electromagnetic waves
We have a single, polarized $TEM_{00}$ and the same for a $TEM_{01}$/or any other. mode relative to the z-axe.
Reformulated questions:
In classical mechanics we have a standing wave. When we look from the side of the propagating axe, we can see these nods. And the amplitude would swing between those nods. So a different frequency for each mode.

Do different TEM-modes have the same frequency?

Each TEM-mode has an intensity distribution, picture 2. What would be the longitudinal picture, like picture 1, but for different TEM-modes.

How do you know, that specific transversal intensity profile, is of this specific TEM-mode?


Thanks in advanced!
Edit: Picture 1, before this, we did not have the mirrors


(The old questions in order):
In classical mechanics when we look from the side of the propagating axe, we can see these nods. And the amplitude would swing between those nods. So a different frequency for each mode.

In waves different TEM-modes, have the same frequency...or am I wrong? I don't get the analogy, if there is one.

Furthermore, what does the line in between the intensity profile white bulges represent? What I really mean is:
When we watch animations of an electromagnetic wave, there are to waves perpendicular to each other and they are perpendicular to the propagating vector. Like in the first picture, which represents it for the $TEM_{00}$ mode (right?). How would that picture from the side look, if I were to have other modes.

We can add modes together to get new intensity profiles. How is this different from interference of waves?



General tip: Let's not have posts look like revision histories

sorry, is noted

I have found this very helpful website
and this picture:



Do different TEM-modes have the same frequency?


What a TEM-mode essentially means is written in a)
The reflected arrow-path consists of oscillators. On every little oscillator, is an applied force from the E-field. If we would look from the side, view from c, there will be spots where longitudinally are more oscillators aligned. Hence, we would see more radiating (brighter intensity) from these ( = the white bulges).
The transversal mode is not characterized by the frequency. It is more about the path between the mirrors until it would repeat itself.

2.Each TEM-mode has an intensity distribution, picture 2. What would be the longitudinal picture, like picture 1, but for different TEM-modes.

...and therefore the longitudinal picture would be just a different path in between the two mirrors, resulting again (from the sideview) in different intensity distribution, because again longitudinally oscillators would be aligned differently.


How do you know, that specific transversal intensity profile, is of this specific TEM-mode?



Therefore: I~|E|

Correct me if I am wrong:

wrong
I came to the conclusion. Think of the propagating light wave in form of a plane wave. Two plane waves can be add together, the superposition would have these lines of zero amplitude. We cannot see the the field. But the intensity its radiating, i.e the black lines in between the white bulges.
The mentioned addition, uses the principle of interference.


First of all, the figure you are showing is the plane wave, it propagates in a free space with no delimitations. Waves $TE_{mn}$ are attributed to a waveguide (see for example a rectangular, circular waveguides). The bilges you see is an intensity of a wave on a screen (it might be on a section of a waveguide or outside of a waveguide). Since only plane wave can propagate in the free space, there is no contradiction because on the output of a guide if you take a direction the wave is locally flat (see the far field).
Correction : a wave is only TEM, there is no $TEM_{000}$
As for your questions:

There is particular physics of the propagation in a waveguide, for the same energy, there might be several modes with the same energy. All depends how you excite them. Depending on a source, there can be one mode or another.

It is an intensity of an output wave. Lets say that there can be multiple reflections of a plane wave in a guide and since wave interfere with each other you can have black and white spots. The most important is that the wave in a guide is not plane one, there might be $H$ or $E$ components along the direction of propagation (see the waveguides physics)

Wave can interfere, correct, however the picture is a bit more complicated in a rectangular guide, it is hard to say how the wave transforms and how it will interfere since that there are two transversal directions


